# automatic background-image transitions not working in safari but working fine in chrome

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations, keyframe

I am having trouble in finding a solution to this problem where my image is easily transitioning to another image in chrome/opera but in safari my image doesn't change. here is the code:

```css
#home{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    /* background-color: transparent; */
    background: url('imgs/1000x1000/2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    background-position: center;

    background-attachment: fixed;

    -webkit-background-size:cover;

    background-size: cover;


    -webkit-animation-name: anim;
    
    -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    /* -webkit-animation-play-state: running; */


    animation-name: anim;
    animation-direction: alternate-reverse;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    /* animation-play-state: running; */
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

    -webkit-transition: 5s;
    transition: 5s;

}
@-webkit-keyframes anim{
    0%{
        background: url('imgs/1000x1000/3.png');
    
    }
    20%{
        background: url('imgs/1200x1200/1.png');
    
    }
    40%{
        background: url('imgs/1000x1000/2.png');
    
    
    }
    60%{
        background: url('imgs/1000x1000/3.png');

    }
    80%{
        background: url('imgs/1000x1000/1.png');

    }

    100%{
        background: url('imgs/1200x1200/2.png');
    
    }
}  
@keyframes anim{
    0%{
        background-image: url('imgs/1000x1000/3.png');
    
    }
    20%{
        background-image: url('imgs/1200x1200/1.png');
    
    }
    40%{
        background-image: url('imgs/1000x1000/2.png');
    
    
    }
    60%{
        background-image: url('imgs/1000x1000/3.png');

    }
    80%{
        background-image: url('imgs/1000x1000/1.png');

    }

    100%{
        background-image: url('imgs/1200x1200/2.png');
    
    }
}
```

```html
    <section id="home">
        <div class="dets">
            <h2>Hello!</h2>
            <p>You are great!!!!!!!</p>
        </div>
    </section>
```

If I change background: url(); to background: red; or any other color, color transitions work perfectly fine in safari. any suggestions?

Here are some images i used

Comment: I think Safari struggles with background attachment fixed, though I can’t immediately see why that should be the problem here. Could you put some images in your snippet so we can run it.

Comment: I didn't know how to add images but i think i succeeded. thanks for your comment!

Comment: You need to put in the full url.